# a already symlinked file when gitignored will work fine or not?

Tags: git, symlink

I have created a symlink in the shared directory of production. if i set this file to gitignore and push the code on github master where it will not be visible now.
So please tell me the symlink for that file will work fine or not?

Answer (score 0):

The symlink will still work locally (in your local repo)

And it won't be in your github repo at all, since it is ignored: ignoring the symlink won't affect its function.

Comment: the symlink file is in my shared directory on production,so when i push the code to repository with ignoring the symlink file and then pushing the code to production,will work fine?

Comment: @AbidIqbal yes: the symlink won't be erased by that push, it will still be there.